# Isn't a homogeneous differential equation always solvable trivially?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a homogeneous differential equation (linear or non-linear, of any order), defined in the sense here
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomogeneousOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html (the first definition), or equivalently here 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation#Homogeneous_linear_differential_equations.

This type of differential equation is always solvable, right? It appears to me the trivial function $y(x)=0$ for all $x$ always satisfies this equation. However, I heard someone say there may be homogeneous differential equations that do not have a solution, so I wanted to make sure my conclusion is correct.

Comment: The MathWorld page clearly points out that there are two meanings of this word. One applies only to linear equations, in which case, yes, the zero function is always a solution.

Comment: @symplectomorphic A follow up quesiton if you don't mind: why does the definition I'm asking about (no function of $x$ only) apply only to linear equations? Is it just a convention or are there technical reasons?

Comment: In practical problems, there are often initial conditions to be satisfied by the solution. Although the zero function is a solution to the equation, it usually doesn’t satisfy those conditions. The situation is similar with systems of homogeneous linear equations: although the zero vector is always a solution to the system, we’re usually more interested in finding non-trivial solutions.